# How can I use ng-bind-html inside my directive?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using templates based on my JSON. So, I can't really use my ng-bind-html like I would normally do.

Seems like the only option I have is to use my sanitized html inside an directive.
Looking for similar questions, I couldn't figure it out how to apply in my case.
Yes, I am pretty newbie into angular.

I'm currently receiving this data from my controller:

```
$scope.safecontainers = $sanitize($scope.containersmsg);
```

In my html would normally be like this:

```
<p ng-bind-html="containersmsg"></p>
```

But I don't want this, I need to use this ng-bind-html inside a directive!

Some people have talked about $compile, but I couldn't really figure it out how to apply in my case.

**EDIT:**

Based on comments, i'll add more code to help you guys further understand my goal.

Inside my index.html I'm declaring the controllers needed and calling my

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

Then, based on what I receive, i'll load one view or another:

```
      <div ng-if='setores[0].SetorTema == "1"'>
        <theme-one titulo="{{setores[0].SetorNome}}" logo="
            {{setores[0].SetorLogo}}" evento="{{evento[0].EventoNome}}">
        </theme-one>
 // I omitted some of the parameters because they ain't relevant
      </div>
```

My template is like this: (Just a little part of it to avoid much useless code)

```
  <section class="target">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="" ng-repeat="banner in title">
            <div class="target-title">{{ banner.BannerLevelTitulo }}
            </div>
            <div class="target-desc">{{banner.BannerLevelDescricao}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-hidden">
        <div class="target-image"><img ng-src="{{targetimage}}" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is the controller I want my sanitized code.

```
hotsite.controller('containerController', function($scope, $http, $sanitize) 
{


$scope.containers = [];
$scope.containersmsg = '';
$scope.safecontainers = $sanitize($scope.containersmsg);

$http.get('/Admin/rest/getContainer')
.then(function onSuccess(response) {
    var data = response.data;
    $scope.containers = data;

      $scope.containers = response.data.filter(containers => 
containers.ContainerAtivo);
      $scope.containersmsg = $scope.containers[0].ContainerDesc;
  })
 .catch(function onError(response) {
    var data = response.data;
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

This is a piece of my directive:

```
    angular.module('hotsiteDirectives', [])
.directive('themeOne', function($compile) {
  var ddo = {};

     ddo.restrict = "AE";
     ddo.transclude = true;

     ddo.scope = {
         titulo: '@',
         ...
         (a lot of other scope's)
         contimg: '@'
     };

     ddo.templateUrl = 'app/directives/theme-one.html';

     return ddo;
 })
```

And yes, I am calling the ngSanitize

```
var hotsite = angular.module('hotsite',['ngRoute', 'hotsiteDirectives', 
'ngSanitize']);
```

**TL;DR**

This is how my code looks like inside a directive, with raw html and not rendered:

[image: thats how it is now]

This is how it works with ng-bind-html, formatted html

[image: That's how should look like]

If I do put this inside my view

```
    <p ng-bind-html="containersmsg"></p>
```

It will be alright, all of it working like it should.

BUT, I need to call this only inside my directive, and I don't know how to do it.
So, with this context:

**How can I put my sanitized html inside my directive and template?**

Comment: have you tried `$sce.trustAsHtml(...)` ? as well as other [trustAs and parseAs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) functions?

Comment: it's not really clear what your issue is here.  where is the directive declared?  how are you creating the `$scope` properties for the various properties you are passing?  why are you storing this kind of HTML in a data variable instead of a normal template file?  The only reason to store HTML in a variable is if you plan on having your users modify the content, but it's not usually the case that users would be modifying (or even know about) angular properties.....  This just feels like you are trying to use AngularJs in a way other than how it was intended....

Comment: @Claies I am passing those variables into other controllers, I just omitted the code because It has no value to the question. 
And yes, my users are going to modify the content.
The question is: How can I use a sanitized data inside my directive?

Comment: it will take some work, since this ***is not how angular was designed to be used***.  Giving your users the names of properties that *might exist in the `$scope`*, asking them to use angular syntax, and hoping they don't make typos or page edits that could modify data in unexpected ways, unchecked, seems like **A REALLY BAD IDEA**.

Comment: the whole point of the `$sce` is to protect you from malicious code that could be entered into HTML snippets.  By having your users modify the HTML directly with angular syntax, you are essentially trying to allow exactly the thing the `$sce` is there to prevent.

Comment: Sorry Claies, I think I misunderstood what you meant then. I'll edit my question to give some more clarification to what I want.

Comment: so what is `$scope.containersmsg`?  is that a string containing the entire template file, `ng-if`, directive, etc?  again, I go back to, why are you storing HTML as strings rather than using actual template files?  Something about this still isn't adding up.

Comment: @Claies I'm using an FCK Editor that throws me html formatted text in my application that generates my data.
$scope.containersmsg will throw exactly this html "sanitized".
I just can't figure it out on how to put it inside my custom directive.
You keep talking about actual template files... can you give me some example of it?

Comment: you really need to provide a [mcve] showing what you are trying to do;  as it stands now, it's not really clear what part of your code is needing to be compiled (i.e. what part is in the FCK Editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even have to trust the html to render it using [`ngBindHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) because the directive already does it for you. You basically need to create a parameter attribute for your directive to hold the html string, so, inside the directive's template, you use `ng-bind-html="myParam"`.

The following snippet implements a simple demonstration of creating a directive that receives and renders an html input parameter that comes from a controller.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myHtml = '<div><b>Hello!</b> I\'m an <i>html string</i> being rendered dynamicalli by <code>ngBindHtml</code></div>';
  })
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      template: '<hr><div ng-bind-html="html"></div><hr>',
      scope: {
        html: '='
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <my-directive html="myHtml"></my-directive>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is already in my module declaration mate, I didn't put in my code because I thought it was implicit.

Comment: @AndréSousa So, it should've been working. Please, provide the rest of your code, I can't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: I just added some more code, sorry if I couldn't make myself clear the first time! Please, see if you can understand my goal now.
Btw, thanks for the assist

Comment: @AndréSousa you want to pass an html string as an attribute param to a directive and render it inside the directive?

Comment: Yep! You saying like this make it sound so easy, but thats it.

Comment: @AndréSousa it is indeed easy, it's just a little bit confusing because of how angularjs works. Anyways, I've updated my answer with a proper solution.

Comment: Life saver!
Thank you mate, for real!
By the way, judging by your name I think you speak portuguese as well? If so, could you provide some places where I can improve my angular knowledge? (Both languages are acceptable tho, but for real, thanks again for the time spent into this!)

Comment: @AndréSousa AngularJS is an old framework now  heading to deprecation, so I don't recommend investing time on it unless you really have to. Anyways, best place to learn angularjs principals is on https://docs.angularjs.org in the LEARN section there is tutorials, free courses, etc. You don't need to learn much more than just how the framework works, once you know the basis, it's easier to find the rest when you face problems like this question. Cheers :{D